# Sending email to email address retrieved from database Initiated by session in PHP Array to string conversion?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm attempting to create a system when you initiate a session an email is then sent to the email the user created the account with. I'm having an error which i've tried to solve, but I'm unable to. Here is the error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginSystem\index.php on line 37

I have been using snippets but obviously not applying them correctly:

```
<?php
    require 'assests/database.php';
    session_start();  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>    
<title>Welcome to your web app</title>    
<link rel="stylesheet" stype="text/css" href="assests/style.css">    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>    
</head>    
<body> 
<div class="header">    
  <a href="index.php"> Your App Name</a>    
</div>      
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ): ?>
<?php
    $sql = 'select email from noodles_gamification where ID = "'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $email = "";
    // output data of each row
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $email = $row["email"];    
    /*    
    $recipients = array();    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)) {    
        $recipients = $row[0]['email'];    
    } */
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $body = "E-mail body";
    $headers = "From: noreply@prakashsoft.esy.es" ;
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
<br /> Welcome you are succesfully loggin in!
<a href="assests/logout.php">Logout?</a>
<?php else : ?>
<h1>Please login or register</h1>
<a href="assests/login.php">login</a> or 
<a href="assests/register.php">Register</a>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Which is line 37?

Comment: $sql = 'select email from noodles_gamification where ID = "'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"';

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
`$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
```

to

```
`$email = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`
```

And your query will look something like this

```
$sql = 'select email from noodles_gamification where ID = "'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'"';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$email = "";
// output data of each row
$email = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Hope this will help you (y).